# add rel=nofollw with php in certain section link

Tags: wordpress

I want add rel=nofollow to all link in a certain section(this section show related product in post widget) in wordpress

```
'add_filter('the_content', 'my_nofollow', 10, 1 );
function my_nofollow( $content ) {
    if( is_single() ) 
        return preg_replace_callback('/<a[^>]+/', ' rel=nofollow;', $content);
     else
        return $content;
}'
```

Comment: To apply a filter on a Widget' content it's better to mention the Widget callback... like "widget_search" or "widget_text"... The filter you mentioned here concerns the post' content ! If you don't know which filter to use especially when using plugins, there is a dirty workaround by filtering the sidebar content ! But still, you may have widgets in your footer or in a custom section. So how about you tell us where is Widget located (sidebar.php, footer.php ...) and is it a default widget, custom made or plugin generated?

Comment: thank you.
widget in single post sidebar. i add this section with ux block flatsome theme.
this section id is "block_widget-2".

Comment: By section you mean the Widget Output? Or still you have multiple sections in that widget?

Comment: I have one sidebar in blog post. this contain to section, one: a slider show product. tow: a list of most viewed post. (https://b2n.ir/276004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this without compatibility issue is by  installing [Widget Output Filters](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-output-filters/) ([Github Repo](https://github.com/philipnewcomer/widget-output-filters)). This plugin introduce a new hook 'widget_output' capable of targeting any kind of Widgets. After installing it, you add this to functions.php :

```
function filter_widgets( $widget_output, $widget_type, $widget_id, $sidebar_id ) {

if ( 'block_widget-2' == $widget_id ) {
$widget_output = preg_replace( '/<a([^>]+)>/i', '<a\1 rel="nofollow">', $widget_output );
        }

        return $widget_output;
    }
add_filter( 'widget_output', 'filter_widgets', 10, 4 );
```

To avoid the confusion between any eventual visual ID showing the id attribute and the Widget Registered ID. We can use the following action that would display the Widget ID that we need to use in our widget_output filter.
After adding this code in functions.php

```
add_action('in_widget_form', 'spice_get_widget_id');
function spice_get_widget_id($widget_instance)
{

    // Check if the widget is already saved or not. 

    if ($widget_instance->number=="__i__"){

     echo "<p><strong>Widget ID is</strong>: Pls save the widget first!</p>"   ;


  }  else {

       echo "<p><strong>Widget ID is: </strong>" .$widget_instance->id. "</p>";


    }
}
```

We would be able to see that in Appearance=> Widget Menu in the Widget bloc even if we are not using a form.

[image]

Comment: thank you
this work, but all  link  in sidebar change

Comment: You want all links in Block_widget-2 to have a rel=nofollow attribute ? Please explain your expected result and share with us the final HTML code of your widget...

Comment: yes, i wantr all link in block_widget-2 have rel=nofollow. can you see my site sidebar this link(b2n.ir/276004).

Comment: <div class="post-sidebar">
<div id="secondary"><aside id="block_widget-2"></div><aside id="yuzo_widget-4"></div>
</div></div>

Comment: Did you updated the website? مطالب مرتبط means related products ! Just to clarify things, here the first Widget block_widget-2 is a custom widget and the second is generated by Yuzo Plugin. Ok just to be sure we are talking about a registered widget. I will update my answer to show you how to find the Registered Widget ID and tell me How you see this Widget (Showing Honey pots)  in the dashboard Appearance=>Widgets and what's it's regiestered ID?

Comment: You could be using a Flickity Slider plugin, or your theme is registering a Widget displaying Flickity Slider... When you find that Widget_ID your problem would be solved. Otherwise, we are not speaking about a wordpress widget when the slider is just a loop mentioned in some of your theme' template-parts...

Comment: مطالب مرتبط means related posts(generated by Yuzo Plugin). and block_widget-2 is my related product. I want just block_widget-2 link have rel=nofollw but above code change related posts links too. and honey pot widget id is " block_widget-2 "

Comment: Ok your related product.. How is it generated via a Widget? Did you verified it's Widget ID using the method I added to my answer or just via HTML source?

Comment: How about you share a screenshot of those widgets in your Appearance menu ! It's like  $sidebar_id is being used in your situation... still confusing :)

Comment: yes, I verified widget id by your method. i add  product section to widget with flatsome block.

Comment: Ok! In your website... The code did the opposite it changed the links on the other widget not the whole sidebar either ! Are you or Flatsome block is including them in the same widget container? Can you define a new separate widget container in that sidebar and see if it works?

Comment: thanks a lot.i add another section to sidebar and this link not change. yuzo links are set nofollw I think your code change it. thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped :) If the issue remains on how  flatsome block deals with Flicky slider Widget, you could ask it on their forum or support. It's a premium Theme and I can't even see how it handle things! Good luck